# @ModelAttribute population

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I am creating an object with a `createDummyObjectModel` method, then flow goes to a `loadPage` method where I populate `dummyObject` and add it to the model so that it's accessible to the `showDummyObject` method (which is a get call from
the page).

The issue occurs after I populate `dummyObject` in the `loadPage` method, the flow again 
goes back to `createDummyObjectModel` and it wipes out the data.

What's the best way to resolve this issue? I know @`ModelAttribute` methods are always 
called first.

```
  @Controller
    @SessionAttributes( value = {"abcModel"} )
    public class myController

{
    @RequestMapping( value = "/loadHomePage.html", method = RequestMethod.GET )
    public String loadPage( @ModelAttribute( "abcModel" ) DummyObject dummyObject,
           ModelMap model ) 
    {
           dummyObject = webService.getMyDummyObject("paramters");

           model.addAttribute( "abcModel", dummyObject );

        return "homepage";
    }

    @RequestMapping( value = "/getDummyObjectString.html" )
    public void showDummObject( @ModelAttribute( "abcModel" ) DummyObject dummyObject,
             ModelMap model,
            Writer out ) throws IOException
    {

        String dummyString = dummyObject.toString();
        out.write( dummyString );

    }


    @ModelAttribute( "abcModel" )
    public DummyObject createDummyObjectModel()
    {
        DummyObject dm = new DummyObject();

        return dm;
    }

}
```

Comment: Which model is better suits your needs that is populated.

Comment: didnt get your comment.

Comment: Please explain " the flow again goes back to createDummyObjectModel". When do you notice, that the dummyObject is empty when it should not be?

Answer (score 0):

The @ModelAttribute method should be called by Spring when invoking a method having a @ModelAttribute parameter set to null.
Does your call to the webservice `dummyObject = webService.getMyDummyObject("paramters");` returns you something? I guess Spring calls your `createDummyObjectModel()` again cause your `dummyObject` is null.